# What should be the value of maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode in worklight adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am developing IBM Worklight application. On production, application has about 1-2 thousand users. What should be the value of 'maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode'?

In adapters the value of maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode is 2 (default). 
Application response is good while number of users are less but on heavy load(thousands of user), users are facing issue of connection with sever .

In addition, Backend databases are little bit slow.

```
<wl:adapter name="Authentication"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>Authentication</displayName>
    <description>Authentication</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>blank</domain>
            <port>80</port>         
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="pro1"></procedure>
    <procedure name="pro2"></procedure>
    <procedure name="pro3" securityTest="appSecurityTest"></procedure>

</wl:adapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for performance suggestions then this is not the place for it, and is wholly dependent on your specific machines and their setup.

I suggest that you will read the following materials and make educated changes based on it:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/tuning_worklight_server?lang=en
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r__maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode__element_.html
- http://dw.developer-works.com/article/10013142/Recommended+value+for+maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode
- search more online...

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.Actually, While many users use the application concurrently, Some their request doesn't even reach at server (Found from Logs). Is there any connection limit due to 'maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode' ?